# jquery .on() only works once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with multiple checkbox inputs:

```
<form>
<table id="table">
    <tr>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="1" class="someClass"></td>
      <td><input type="checkbox" value="1" class="someClass"></td>...
```

And some jquery that refreshes the table from another file when the box is checked/unchecked:

```
$(".someClass").on("change", function() {
        $('#edit').ajaxSubmit(); //Submitting the form with id "edit"
        $("#table").load("tablerefresh");
 });
```

My problem is that when I check/uncheck a box, the table will refresh only once, and it should do it every time I check/uncheck the box, I've looked everywhere and can't seem to find a solution. Any ideas?

Comment: You might want to try hooking on an element that is not going to be reload (e.g. `<form>` in your example) with an appropriate filter so it only handles the events from the checkbox.

Comment: the `.on` should be executed on a parent element that doesnt change or `document`.

Comment: You're code seems fine. Check this out. http://jsfiddle.net/LEukL/
Look at your console and see if maybe something is crashing your code and that's why it stops executing.

Comment: For some context to the other comments or answers, [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) has documentation about delegated events which you're supposed to use here.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is probably a matter of delegation, since `#table` doesn't change, use it as the scope, targeting `.someClass` inside:

```
$("#table").on("change", ".someClass", function() {
  $('#edit').ajaxSubmit(); //Submitting the form with id "edit"
  $("#table").load("tablerefresh");
});
```

Note:

You can also use `delegate()`:

```
$("#table").delegate(".someClass", "change", function(){
  //Code
});
```

Comment: Tried them both, they both work perfectly, thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
$(document).on("change", ".someClass" , function() {
        $('#edit').ajaxSubmit(); //Submitting the form with id "edit"
        $("#table").load("tablerefresh");
 });
```